# how to display simple html string with <img> <p> tag in flash builder 4?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, image

`hello <img src="http://i1.sinaimg.cn/home/deco/2009/0330/logo_home.gif" />world`

Comment: How to format: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. How to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. I recommend reading both.

Comment: I second Matt Ball's recommendation. Are you just trying to insert an image between two labels? Is this all supposed to be included in a single line of text (which Saito provided an answer for)? More information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Flex has a htmlText in Text Component.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    backgroundGradientColors="[#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF]">
    <mx:Text width="100%" color="blue" fontStyle="italic" fontSize="14">
        <mx:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[
                <img src="http://i1.sinaimg.cn/home/deco/2009/0330/logo_home.gif" />world
            ]]>
        </mx:htmlText>
    </mx:Text>
</mx:Application>
```

like this to display html.